# Python - how to stop socket recv() waiting if there is no coming data sent from client

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I'm leanring how sockets work and trying to do some simple things.
My client is **NOT** sending anything to the server, and the server will not receive anything. But the problem is that the server socket will be always waiting for nothing. I want it to do something else if there is no available coming data from the client side. The `if statement` does not help end its waiting.

**Server.py:**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
hostname = socket.gethostname()
host = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
port = 9090
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen(10)
con, addr = server.accept()  
msg = con.recv(2048)
if not msg:
    con.send('hello world'.encode('utf-8'))
    con.close()
    server.close()
else:
    con.send('hi Client I received it'.encode('utf-8'))
    con.close()
    server.close()
```

**Client.py:**

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('192.155.11.79', 9090))
data = client.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
print('From server side: ', data)
client.close()
```

Comment: If your server waits for a connection, it blocks until a connection from a client is made. If you want to do something else when there is no connection, then it is better to use threads.

Comment: @VasilisG. like non-blocking?

Comment: Yes, you need a thread that will listen for connections and another thread to do the work you want to do.